# Is it possible to change some specified section headerView height in uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

In my app, this is a collectionView in my main view controller, the items are many kinds of images, one kind is a section.

I want to add a label to per section header, so users can input or edit their throughs about some kind of images. Because of this, I must adjust the height of label when lines of text changes.

So, how can I change the height of some specified section header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [layout invalidateLayout] to update all headerViews and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with *uicollectionviewlayout*, I assume you are using a custom one.

You can set the `frame` property of the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, which is of type CGRect,  for the cell which is representing the header.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a custom layout.And in my case, editing the lable after the cells display.

Comment: Then I try to using `[layout invalidateLayout]` to update all headerViews, and it works well.Thanks all the same :)